# Browser not displaying image from database

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I'm currently working on Entity framework crud operation, I wonder why image is not displaying in the browser.

This is my Controller to push the image to database using model (Database first approach) ->

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Product p) // Receives the products model here
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                EFDBFirstDatabaseEntities db = new EFDBFirstDatabaseEntities();

                // Photo managing
                if (Request.Files.Count >= 1)
                {
                    var file = Request.Files[0];
                    var imgBytes = new Byte[file.ContentLength];
                    file.InputStream.Read(imgBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
                    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length);
                    p.Photo = base64String;
                }

                db.Products.Add(p); // adding new object values to the products class
                db.SaveChanges(); // updating the database 
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

A view to display it ->

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><img src="data:image;base64,@item.Photo"/></td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I have converted the image to base64 string and uploaded into the database.

PLEASE HELP ME TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE.

Comment: Have you checked the generated page source for HTML character substitutions in the base64 strings? Shouldn't happen but Razor occasionally messes up.

Comment: I dont know what happened, i just deleted whole data in database and inserted new values into it, now it's displaying image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what happened, i just deleted whole data in database and inserted new values into it, now it's displaying image.